# Installing SAP ECC 6.0

Tags: sap-erp

Is it possible to install SAP ECC 6.0 on a local dev box? I need to test integrating with with SAP from another application (through BAPIs) and am having a hard time finding any type of developer edition or even a virtual appliance that I can quickly test with. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but if you want to test against BAPIs the only thing you're left with is either a full-blown installation and customization project  - I think we can safely rule that out - or an IDES installation. The reason is that with all of the free test drives I know of, you only get the development environment, but not the ECC core with the business logic - and the BAPIs are part of the ECC core.

Take a look at http://www.consolut.net/en/s/sap-ides-access.html - they seem to offer a free IDES access that might be sufficient for your purposes. If you want to install IDES on your own box, you need to be a SAP Customer or Partner with a valid license - if you are, go to service.sap.com/ides - and remember to buy a Really Big Machine[tm].

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks great. Just briefly, why will the download listed by Chris not work?

Comment: Well, let's assume that you want to use BAPI_SALESORDER_WHATEVER. This  BAPI is part of the ECC Core package. The ABAP Developer Editions simply do not contain the ECC Core packages. It's like "I really need MS Project, but I've only got the MS Office Home Edition with Word and Excel in it".

Besides, even if you got the ECC Core packages and installed them, you'd get a naked, empty system - you'll have to configure it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The SAP developer editions are available for download from here:

- http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/nw-downloads

You probably want to try **SAP NetWeaver 7.01 SR1 SP3 ABAP Developer Edition** first. It's not exactly a full-blown ECC system, but has all of the core ABAP stuff you'll probably need.